# PHP spreedsheet dont download the excel file

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, excel, symfony

im working with php spreedsheet for excel files, im trying to give an array with data to download on an excel.

Im doing this request with ajax. This is my code. My code is on a symfony 3.4.
I tried with headers but when i click on download file, the ajax request say ok but dont give me the excel file

```
$datos = $request->request->get('datos');
                $datos = json_decode($datos,true);

                $cuenta = count($datos);
                $spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
                $cuentaColumnas = count($datos[0]); 
                $letra = "a";
                $user =  $this->getUser()->getUser();  

                for ($i=0; $i <$cuenta ; $i++) { 

                    $numero = 1;

                        for ($j=0; $j < $cuentaColumnas ; $j++) {
                            $informacion = $datos[$i][$j];

                            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($letra.$numero,$informacion);
                            $numero++;

                        }

                        $letra++;

                }


                // Set active sheet index to the first sheet, so Excel opens this as the first sheet

                 // create the writer
                $writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
                $writer->save();


                return $writer;
```

Comment: You cant download file using ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually you can´t download a file using Ajax, when you create the excel file with PHP you are creating it on the server side and you have to ask for the server to download it. So if you want to download it what you can do is to do a little trick creating an hidden anchor link with the URL of the file that you just created with PHP and click it when ajax return success.

This is an example of the anchor link, put it on the html view.

```
<a href="replace_src_of_the_file" download id="hiddenDonwloader" hidden></a>
```

And here is an example of the Ajax. When you reach "success" meaning that the file has been created successfully then you can be sure to download it. If you don't know the name of the file previously, then you can return the file name too and get it in the "success" and change the href attribute before click it.

```
$.ajax({
headers: {
// Put your headers here
  _your_header_
},
url: url_of_php, // put your url here
type: 'POST', 
dataType: 'text',
data: {
  datos: data // put your data to send here
},
error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  console.log(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
},
success: function (data) {
//Here we click the anchor link be sure that the href attribute is right
  document.getElementById('hiddenDonwloader').click();
},
});
```

Hope that helps!